# How to update last column of a table with dictionary object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table in which the last column of every row needs to be replaced with a dynamically generated dictionary key value pair.The following is my table structure,

```
<table id="example">
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>T1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>D1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I wanted to append another column at the end of each row. Just like this,

```
<table id="example">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>T1</td>
    <td>T2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>D1</td>
    <td>D2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have this input with me

> var dict = {
>               "t1": "T2",
>               "t2": "D2"
>           }
>   How will I do it using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented by using the following code,

```js
var dict = {
            "t1": "T2",
            "t2": "D2"
            }
var count = 0;
$.each (dict, function (field, value) {
    $('#example tr').each(function() {
        if($("tr").index(this) == count){
              $(this).find('td:last').after('<td>' + value + '</td>');
          }
      });
    count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>T1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code:

```
 // append the <td> inside each found <tr> in the table
 $("#example > tr").each(function(index){
     $(this).append("<td>" + value[index] + "</td>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) function to get last `td` in every `tr` by using jQuery selector like this:

```js
var dict = {
  "t1": "T2",
  "t2": "D2"
}
var index = 0;

function start() {
  var x = $('#example tr')
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    row = x[i]
    var valInDic = index == 0 ? dict.t1 : dict.t2;
    index++;
    $(row).append('<td>' + valInDic + '</td>')
    if (index == 2)
      index = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>T1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td>D1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick=start() ">Start</button>
```

I hope this helps ;)